# How to replace element in list in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, replace

I have two `list` variables:

```
a = ["a", "b"]
b = ["a (x)"]
```

I need to find and replace all elements in list `a` with elements from list `b` where substring of element before  `(` from list `b` is equal to element from list `a`. So I need to get this:

```
a = ["a (x)", "b"]
b = ["a (x)"]
```

It is a bit complicated to exlplain, but I hope you understand.

This is what I have so far, but I don't know how to continue.

```
for bx in b:
    for ax in a:
        if ax == bx[:bx.find(" (")]:
            #I don't know what to do next
```

Do you have some ideas, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one way. First create a dictionary mapping, then apply it in a list comprehension.

```
a = ["a", "b"]
b = ["a (x)"]

b_dict = {v.split(' ')[0]: v for v in b}

a = [b_dict.get(i, i) for i in a]

# ['a (x)', 'b']
```

Comment: This seems good but I need it to keep going if there is "b (x)" in list b and so on.. What I posted what just an example

Comment: This will still work if you had "b (x)" in list `b`.